# created a mesh, but the front and back are different

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I created a mesh in code.

The mesh is well made. 4 vertexs and 2 trianlges

However, rendering became different. below the pictures

Why are the front and the back different?

The visible side is transparent on the other side.

What options should I add?

I only entered values for vertex and triangle points.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you created your meshes make sure you applied these:

```
mesh.RecalculateBounds();
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
```

> Any time your modify or create a mesh from scratch  you have to recalculate normals and recalculate bounds.

**After modifying the vertices it is often useful to update the normals to reflect the change. Normals are calculated from all shared [vertices](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateNormals.html).**

Answer (score 0):

You could add "Cull Off" to your shader for render both mesh sides.
By default system renders only face side due to performance reasons,
as mentioned in this post https://answers.unity.com/questions/187252/display-both-sides.html

> The reason is that graphics systems always cull backfaces. The faces
>   are usually determined by the winding order, i.e. the order in which
>   the vertices of a triangle are declared. Backfaces are culled because
>   it's an easy way to conserve computational power - it is usually not
>   necessary to render a face that's turning away from the viewer, such
>   as the other side of an object's mesh, for instance.

and code Example : https://answers.unity.com/questions/209018/cutout-diffuse-shader-visible-from-both-sides-on-a.html